# ESRI ArcGIS Runtime for .NET view non ESRI Vector Tiles

Tags: vector-tiles, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I am trying to view some vector tiles hosted outside of ArcGIS Online/ArcGIS Enterprise on my own tile server (Flat non indexed tiles).
I have been unable to add the Tile Server to the .NET Runtime application.
I think it's because of ESRI's implementation of the Stylesheet baked into the URL.

ESRI wants {level}/{Col}/{row}.pbf  instead of standard placeholders /{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf  (at least that's how you add tile server with the different placeholders)
https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/a6SBLWoOui928qXS/arcgis/rest/services/UAS/VectorTileServer
the stylesheet is found by default with ESRI https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/a6SBLWoOui928qXS/arcgis/rest/services/UAS/VectorTileServer/resources/styles

the URL for ESRI's basemap
https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer

Answer (score 1):

The VectorTileLayer is expecting the service to provide a particular set of metadata and files at particular locations matching how ArcGIS Server does it. So your tile cache would need to follow that pattern as well.
You might want to try and use Fiddler and see which requests are failing or which one is the last request.
Also check the LoadError on the layer itself.